# Whisker Menu search bar

Tags: xfce, whisker

I just updated to Xubuntu 15.04 and am somewhat annoyed in noticing that the search bar in Whisker Menu has disappeared. This is what I currently have:

[image]

I used to have something like this:

[image]

How can I get it back?

Comment: do you have this installed `apt-cache policy xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin`?

Comment: I think so:  "$ sudo apt-cache policy xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin 
xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin:
  Installed: 1.4.3-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1.4.3-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.3-0ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Apparently Whisker Menu Plugin wasn't correctly installed on my system. I followed the following instruction from [this page](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-whisker-menu-1-5-0-on-xubuntu-15-04-xubuntu-14-10-xubuntu-14-04-xubuntu-12-04-linux-mint-17-1-linux-mint-17-and-linux-mint-13-using-xfce/) to reinstall it correctly:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gottcode/gcppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin
$ xfce4-panel --restart
```

Comment: yes, that what you should've tried at first place to reinstall/reconfigure it.